# GCP Dataflow UDF import files

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-dataflow, user-defined-functions

I'm using the PubSub to Elastic Dataflow template and I need to do some enrichment, like XML parsing.

I have two issues:

1. Can I split my code into many files and import them using UDF and how?
2. Can I install external libraries? I read only plain js files are supported, but then read this article and I'm not sure if applies to Dataflow UDFs or how to implement it: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-npm-library-in-google-bigquery-udf-8aef01b868f4

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what type of UDF you are talking about here ? Are you simply trying to apply some intermediate function to your data processed by the template before being written to Elastic Search ?

Comment: Hi @chamikara , I need to parse xml content and grok and I'm thinking on importing libraries for that. Tried to build a file using webpack with no success.

Comment: To import a new library and to add a new Beam DoFn (for additional processing), you'll have to modify the Dataflow template or run the pipeline manually. Any additional libraries can simply be imported by adding relavent jars to the CLASSPATH at job submission. All jars in CLASSPATH will be staged by Dataflow by default  (if you are using Beam Python see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/)

Comment: I was thinking on importing javascript libraries building a single js file.

Comment: Beam does not currently offer a way to directly use Javascript libraries. You might be able to use it if there's an associated Python/Java/Go library. Please see the Apache Beam Website for more details - https://beam.apache.org/get-started/beam-overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was almost there. I wasnt building the single js file properly.

src/index.js

```js
var convert = require("xml-js");

module.exports.data_process = function (inJson) {
  var xml = "<XML CONTENT>";
  var result1 = convert.xml2json(xml, { compact: true, spaces: 4 });
  var parsed = JSON.parse(result1);
  var some_field = parsed.some.field
  var obj = JSON.parse(inJson);
  obj.some_field = some_field;
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
};
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: "xmllib",
  },
};
```

build webpack

`npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`

Then add to the end of `main.js`

```js
function process(d) {
    c = xmllib.data_process(d);
    return c;
}
```

Now you can use "process" as your dataflow udf function name.

Solution based on this article: https://blog.salrashid.dev/articles/2020/bq-udf-protobuf/